# Entity Framework like query get input from textbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Get runtime input value from textbox and then search based on the input first character onwards using like query

For example --> Allow, Apple, Aero, Air, Aata, Auto, Basket, Car, Box, Ajax when the user presses A on textbox mean it fetch the data related A for that I need an EF query so friends please suggest your idea

```
var areaname = cnx.village_master 
                  .Where(abd => bd.village_name.StartsWith("txtareacustomer.Text")
                  .ToList();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change:

```
string strValue = txtareacustomer.Text;
var areaname = cnx.village_master.Where(abd => bd.village_name.StartsWith(strValue).ToList();
```